# I have a code that displays oldest file name in a file directory, but how to modify that code so that it shows oldest file date instead of file name?

Tags: vba, excel

The below code shows oldest file name in a file directory, but I am interested in knowing the oldest file date, but not the oldest file name.

```
Sub oldestdate()

Range("G10").Value = GetOldestFile("xxxxx\yyyy\gggggg\uuuuuu")

End Sub


Public Function GetOldestFile(ByVal FileFolder As String, _
                              Optional ByVal FileMask As String = "*.*", _
                              Optional ByVal FullName As Boolean = True) As String

   Dim FoundFile        As String
   Dim FileDT           As Date

   Dim OldestFile       As String
   Dim OldestDT         As Date

   Dim FS As Object

   '// Get rid of any terminating '\' just to get to a known state
   If Right(Trim(FileFolder), 1) = "\" Then
      FileFolder = Left(FileFolder, Len(Trim(FileFolder)) - 1)
   End If

   '// Get First file found in described folder
   FoundFile = Dir$(FileFolder & "\" & FileMask)

   '// Default return date
   OldestDT = Now

   Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   '// Loop through the rest of the files in that folder
   Do Until FoundFile = ""

      FileDT = FS.GetFile(FileFolder & "\" & FoundFile).DateCreated

      '// Compare Current File datetime with oldest found
      If FileDT < OldestDT Then
         OldestFile = FoundFile
         OldestDT = FileDT
      End If

      '// Get next file
      FoundFile = Dir$
   Loop

   Set FS = Nothing

   GetOldestFile =  Format(OldestDT, "mm/dd/yyyy")

End Function
```

Please check the code and let me know if you have any questions or comments.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour], and fix your tags - that is not VB.NET code

Comment: fixed it. It was just a typo.

Comment: You already have it in your code: `FileDT` or  returns the date, so pick up the value of `OldestDT` at the end to get the date..

Comment: `GetOldestFile = format(oldestdt,"mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the reply. your code change works, but it shows date as 12/19/2017 00:00. Can I remove the time value (00:00) somehow ?

Comment: format the cell into which it is placed as `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: @ScottCraner At few instances I am getting incorrect oldest values (To be clear, it is showing today's date and time in those incorrect instances). I am wondering why it is happening so ?

Comment: Even after doing all the changes to code the displayed oldest date values are being incorrect ? I tried debugging the code and find out why but couldn't track the reason, Can you please look into and let me know why ?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, In the above code I was finding the oldest file date in a fodler, but can you please let me know how to modify this code to find most recent file date of all the files in a folder ?

Comment: @ScottCraner In the above code I was finding the oldest file date in a fodler, but can you please let me know how to modify this code to find most recent file date of all the files in a folder ?

Comment: change your date compare logic to find the newest date. :)